# C# Regex Parsing Or Names

Tags: c#, regex, itext

I am pulling data from a printable PDF using iTextSharp.  This is the text that I have extracted:

```
Borrower: Guarantor:
{{0_SH}} By: {{1_SH}} (seal)
By: (seal)
Print Name:
Print Name:
Phillip Moore Phillip Moore
Date: {{1_DH}}
2/23/2022
Title: Owner
Date: {{0_DH}}
2/23/2022
12 of 12 (LOC 2020) Borrower Initials {{0_IH}}
```

And I have written this regex routine:

```
string pattern = @"Print\sName:\s(?'guarantor1'[a-zA-Z|\s|-|-|'|,|.|&|\d]+)\n";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(fullText);
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    string guarantor1 = matches[0].Groups["guarantor1"].Value;
    return guarantor1.Trim();
}
```

But the extracted data from the regex for guarantor1 is Phillip Moore Phillip Moore.  I need just the first part Phillip Moore.  Any ideas how to parse this correctly?  There could also be a middle name or initial.

Comment: It seems that the reason that the name is printed twice, is because the Borrower Name = Guarantor Name. Have you tried reading the data from the fields? Do you have a sample PDF? The following may (or may not) be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69353784/itext7-pdf-to-blob-c-sharp/69364767#69364767 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68941615/is-itext7-available-in-vb-net-or-only-c-sharp/68946796#68946796 .  They're for iText7, but I believe that iTextSharp has something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the last occurrence of `Print Name:` and then match as least as possible of the allowed chars until you encounter the same using a backreference until the end of the string.

Note that `\s` can also match a newline.

```
\bPrint\sName:\n(?!Print\sName)(?'guarantor1'[a-zA-Z\s',.&\d\--]+?)(?= \1$)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YeyOZc/1) and a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/P1NTVE).

If there  should also be a match without the double naming, the space and the backreference to group 1 can be optional.

```
\bPrint\sName:\n(?!Print\sName)(?'guarantor1'[a-zA-Z\s',.&\d\--]+?)(?=(?:\s\1)?$)
```

See another [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1QZPIk/1).

Example code

```
string pattern = @"\bPrint\sName:\r?\n(?!Print\sName)(?'guarantor1'[a-zA-Z\s',.&\d\--]+?)(?= \1\r?$)";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(fullText);
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    string guarantor1 = matches[0].Groups["guarantor1"].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(guarantor1.Trim());
}
```

Output

```
Phillip Moore
```