# PDFGeneration in VB.Net using iText: Trailer not found (iText.Kernel.PdfException)

Tags: vb.net, exception, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I have inherited the following code to generate a PDF:

```vb
' Generate letter
   
Dim oMemory_Document_Writer As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
Dim oPDF_Document_Writer As PdfWriter = New PdfWriter(oMemory_Document_Writer)

If sLang = "D" Then
    sTemplate_Based_On_Language = cTemplate_D
Else
    sTemplate_Based_On_Language = cTemplate_F
End If
    
Dim oPDF_Reader_Form_With_Fields As PdfReader = New PdfReader(sTemplate_Based_On_Language)
Dim oPDF_Document_Form_Filled_Out As PdfDocument = New PdfDocument(oPDF_Reader_Form_With_Fields, oPDF_Document_Writer)
Dim oForm_Letter As iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm = iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(oPDF_Document_Form_Filled_Out, True)
Dim oForm_Fields As IDictionary(Of String, iText.Forms.Fields.PdfFormField)
    
oForm_Fields = oForm_Letter.GetFormFields()    
oForm_Fields.Item(PDF_Variables.Letter.Nom).SetValue(oClient.Name)
oForm_Fields.Item(PDF_Variables.Letter.Adresse).SetValue(oClient.Adresse)
    
sBarcode = sCode
oForm_Fields.Item(PDF_Variables.Letter.BarCode.Bar).SetValue(GED_Code128b(sBarcode))
oForm_Fields.Item(PDF_Variables.Letter.BarCode.Text).SetValue("Code " & sBarcode )

oForm_Letter.FlattenFields()
oPDF_Reader_Form_With_Fields.Close()
    ' V Exception thrown in next line V
oPDF_Document_Form_Filled_Out = New PdfDocument(New PdfReader(New System.IO.MemoryStream(oMemory_Document_Writer.ToArray()))) 
oPDF_Document_Form_Filled_Out.CopyPagesTo(1, oPDF_Document_Form_Filled_Out.GetNumberOfPages(), oPDF_Document_Result)
oPDF_Document_Form_Filled_Out.Close()
```

It throws an exception in the indicated line

I read several threads here related to this issue, but none of the solutions have worked for me so far.

How do I fix this error?

[Here](https://rentry.org/vtfoe2) is the full StackTrace

If I call oPDF_Document_Form_Filled_Out.Close() before ([as suggested by mkl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76680020/pdfgeneration-in-vb-net-using-itext-trailer-not-found-itext-kernel-pdfexceptio#comment135192403_76680020) and other posts, I get this exception : "System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed file." ([Stacktrace](https://rentry.org/pumi2))

Comment: You forgot to close the former `oPDF_Document_Form_Filled_Out`.

Comment: I tried that already as I read multiple times that that might be the issue, but then I get the following exception : "System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed file.'"

Comment: Have you closed it before closing the reader?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean, I closed it in the line before the one that causes the exception

Comment: What version of _iText_ are you using? The posted code seems to be reading an existing PDF. Do you have the code that creates the _template_ PDF? If not, please provide a sample template PDF.

Comment: You may consider using [using statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/using). The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69364767/10024425

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to share the PDF, it is pre-generated in Adobe and contains the 4 fields indicated in the code I posted. I am using version 7.0.8.0

Comment: Unfortunately, we're at an impasse. If you can't provide a sample PDF that's representative of the file you're using, then there's no way to test a solution which means it's unlikely that anyone here can help you.

Comment: *I'm not sure I get what you mean, I closed it in the line before the one that causes the exception''* - you have to close it even before `oPDF_Reader_Form_With_Fields.Close()`. The `PdfDocument` has been opened with that `PdfReader`. Thus, it may need that reader still during closing.

Comment: Closing the PdfDocument (oPDF_Document_Form_Filled_Out) before closing the PdfReader (oPDF_Reader_Form_With_Fields) as suggested by @mkl solved the issue, thank you very much!

Comment: Shall I make that an actual answer or do you want to answer yourself?

Comment: You add it, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you first create a `PdfDocument` in `oPDF_Document_Form_Filled_Out` and thereafter you use its output for further processing.

To use the output of the first `PdfDocument`, though, it must be closed. Otherwise it's incomplete. You forgot that in your code.

You do close the `PdfReader` that `PdfDocument` has been constructed for. When closing the `PdfDocument`, it may require access to its `PdfReader`. Thus, you must close the `PdfDocument` before closing the `PdfReader`.